# Trying to insert a node at a given position, however I'm getting stuck in an infnite loop

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to add a node at a given position in a linked list, however I'm stuck in an infinite loop for some reasons. When I run the following code, the cout statement in the loop keeps outputting forever. Is this issue happening because I'm doing the loop wrong, or it is because I messed something up with how I used the pointers? This is my first time dealing with pointers and I think I have lost my way.

note: I'm trying to learn how to insert a node at a given position, so the following code is only complete syntaxly.

here is my code:

```
void LList::InsertElement(){

// PRE: the N. O. LList is valid

// POST: a new element thing has been inserted at the 
//      given position of the list.If that position doesn't 
//      exist, the LList will be unchanged.

listnode * temp;
element thing;
int position;
int inc;
inc = 1;
cout << "Enter the position where you want to add the element at: ";
position = read_position();

cout << "Enter the element value: ";
thing = read_element();

temp = new listnode;
temp -> data = thing;

if (listSize==0 && position==1){
    head = temp;
    temp -> next = nullptr;}

else if(position<= listSize){
    temp = head;

    while(inc < position){ // for some reasons this loop is infinite

        temp -> next = temp;

        temp = temp -> next;
        cout << endl<< "NEXT: " << temp -> data;
        inc +=1;
        }

    temp -> data = thing;

    }
else;

}
```

Comment: Well the pointer work is definitely wrong, but I can't see how that loop could be infinite.

Comment: `temp -> next = temp; temp = temp -> next;` looks like you're running in circles...

Comment: if I'm not mistaken a wild pointers points to something that I don't have access to, but if this loop stops at the node before the last. Wouldn't this statement makes the next node(last node) point to the current node (the one before the last)?

Comment: @scohe001Can you please teach me how to make the previous node points to the current node? Because this is what I tried there and looks like I did something goofy.

Comment: What do you mean by "make the previous node points to the current node"? I'm a little confused. If you have a valid list, shouldn't that already be the case? If I were you, I'd start by googling and for how to iterate over a linked list.

Comment: since I'm adding a node at the middle of the list wouldn't at I need the previous node to point to the current new node and have this new node points to the next node. I can make the new node points to the next, but how do I have the previous node points to the current new node?

Comment: @PersonMichael You shouldn't be modifying the list at all until you reach the target node.  (e.g. why should node 1 change when you are adding the new node at position 5?)  Just keep a pointer to the previous node as you go, and once you find the target, go through that pointer to update the previous node.

Comment: @0x5453 It doesn't work for me, Is this what you meant?                                           `prev = temp;
            
       
            temp = temp -> next;
            prev -> next = temp;
            inc +=1;`

Comment: @PersonMichael Yes, except `prev->next = temp` should only be done at the very end once you find the target node.  Currently you are still modifying every node that you visit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, do it like this:

```
while(inc < position)
{ 
// print data     
        cout << endl<< "NEXT: " << temp -> data;
// increment temp to point to next
   temp = temp -> next;
        inc +=1;
 }
```

Your code is:

```
temp -> next = temp; 
temp = temp -> next;
```

these line makes it going over same same data again and again. Kind of loop inside loop , running forever.

Comment: Along with a solution, could you add an explanation of *why* this works, and the OP's code doesn't?

Comment: temp -> next = temp;
 temp = temp -> next;                                                                                                                               these line makes it going over same same data again and again. Kind of  loop inside loop , running forever.

Comment: Thanks, but you can add that to the question, instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping me. This is my final code and it's working because of your help, thank you.

```
current = head;
    while(inc < position){

        current = current -> next;

        inc +=1;
        }

    temp -> next = current -> next;
    current -> next = temp;
```